# How to serve django media files via nginx ?

Tags: django, nginx, media

I'm new at Nginx, I've successfully bound my django project to Nginx. However I can't serve my static files and I guess I set my media folder's location wrongly. Here is my file tree:

```
root_directory
     my_django_project
         ...
         manage.py
         app1
         app2
         media
           admin
           css
           js
           ...
```

And my nginx.conf goes like :

```
        server {
                listen 192.168.1.9:80;
                server_name localhost;
                # site_media - folder in uri for static files                                                                                                

            location /media/  {
            root /home/nazmi/workspace/portal/media/;                                                                                       
                }

location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mov) {
  access_log   off; # po co mi logi obrazków :)                                                                                                              
  expires      30d;
}
                location / {
                        # host and port to fastcgi server                                                                                                    
                        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
                        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
                        fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
                        fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
            fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
                        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
                        }
                access_log      /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
                error_log       /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log;
        }
}
```

When I open my admin page, all css pages give 404 error. Can you tell me that how can I set my media path correctly ?

Answer (score 78):

Here's a example of how I have my nginx servers setup

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/myusername/myproject/static/;
    }
    location /media {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/myusername/myproject/media/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

I serve django with Gunicorn on localhost port 8000. (that's what the proxy_pass is for)

The Nginx wiki [example configuration](http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample) may help you too. Notice in their static file serving they specify allowed filetypes and use 'root' instead of 'alias' but they are similar.

This [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/114945/nginx-issue-with-static-files-serving) question may help.

Comment: To new users: Just don't forget to add `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` because your media files will be ignored by the browser if they are served with the default mimetype of `text/plain`

Comment: I want to server media filed by different urls e.g "media.example.com".  how can I achieve that?

Comment: @j_syk Does this is a vhost?

Comment: remember to reboot the server for the changes to take effect "sudo shutdown -r now" I changed the file many times, but until I restarted the server these changes worked!

Comment: why do you have to restart server when you can restart just nginx? `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`

Comment: You should never restart the server on production. Instead `reload` the nginx server.

Comment: It seems like you need to set the end-backslash.

Comment: why do you use autoindex here?

Answer (score 2):

You have set this:

```
location /media/  {
    root /home/nazmi/workspace/portal/media/;                                                                                       
}
```

This means that the location will be xxx/media/media. Nginx will go to [...]/portal/media and look for a folder called media.
It should rather be like this:

```
location /media/  {
    root /home/nazmi/workspace/portal;                                                                                       
}
```

Also you should remove the trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

If the media file isn't serving, try to set media location as below in the conf file inside the sites-enabled directory. This works for me.

```
location /media {
    root /home/username/projectname/;
```

Comment: Thanks. Above did not work for me, but changing to this worked!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        **alias /home/myusername/myproject/;**
    }
    location /media {
        autoindex on;
        **alias /home/myusername/myproject/;**
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

I bold the different parts according to the previous answer.

Comment: why do we need autoindex here?

Answer (score 0):

```
location /media  {
     alias /home/user/django_app/media; #(locaion of your media folder)                                                                                       
}
```

Try this code in nginx config to serve static and media files for a django applications (without autoindex on settings)