# Django recognizes static address but not media

Tags: python, django

this is my static and media settings in `setting.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')
```

And in my project folder structures, `static` and `media` folders are next to each other.

So when I use this html tag

```
<img src="/static/pic.jpg">
```

Or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/pic.jpg`, it works.

But `<img src="/media/pic.jpg">` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/pic.jpg` doesn't.

How is that Django recognizes `127.0.0.1:8000/static/` as a valid address
But it throws `Page not found (404)` when I'm trying `127.0.0.1:8000/media/` ?

This is my url config

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^home/', 'mysite.views.gohome'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this to your urls.py file

```
if settings.DEBUG :
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    )
```

So, It should looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^home/', 'mysite.views.gohome'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

    if settings.DEBUG :
        urlpatterns += patterns('',
            (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        )
```

> With this you can serve the static media from Django when DEBUG=True
>   (when you are on local computer) but you can let your web server
>   configuration serve static media when you go to production and
>   DEBUG=False

Comment: Thank you. it does the job with DEBUG=True. But how to make it work on the server?

Comment: @AlexJolig that depends on what app server(gunicorn/apache) you will use in production, or if you will have a server to serve static/media files as nginx.

Comment: I'm using nginx in local and on the server

Comment: @AlexJolig you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370658/how-to-serve-django-media-files-via-nginx   also, there is a lot of question in SO about that topic. If you aren't happy with existing answers, try to open a new question.

Comment: Thank you. I added media location in nginx configurations and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Levi's answer, you can do:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

...
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

You need to set `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your settings.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.urls.staticfiles_urlpatterns

The other alternative is:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

...
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I like this last one the most because it's obvious what happens.

Both only serve when DEBUG is True.