# Django media files doesn't work when debug=false

Tags: django, django-views

**`settings.py`**

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data')
MEDIA_URL = '/data/'
```

---

**`urls.py`**

```py
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

handler404 = 'generic.views.invalid_request'
```

When I set DEBUG=False and run the server using
`python manage.py runserver --insecure` all static file are serve successfully but media files doesn't appear. In debug console media urls raise error 500.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: yah done. @ans2human

Comment: Accept the answer that helped you for other readers.

Answer (score 1):

`static` helper function [does not work](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) in DEBUG=False mode. And should not. Serving static/media files with Django in prod [is not recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files). Configure your webserver ([Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370658/how-to-serve-django-media-files-via-nginx), [Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682809/django-static-file-hosting-an-apache),..) to serve these files.

`error 500` - investigate  log files to understand what causes app failure.
`static file are serve successfully` perhaps they are being taken from browsers cache.

Answer (score 0):

I had been Using **[WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/)** which allows your web app to serve its own static files, making it a self-contained unit that can be deployed anywhere without relying on nginx, Amazon S3 or any other external service.

**1 - Install with pip:**

> `pip install whitenoise`

**2** - Edit your `settings.py` file and add **WhiteNoise** to the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` list, above all other middleware apart from Django’s `SecurityMiddleware`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

Thats All you need to serve static files without configuring any third party server.

Comment: WhiteNoise is not supposed to serve media files, only static files. It only serves files that exist when the server is started, so for that reason it's not suitable for media files.

Answer (score 0):

In order to serve MEDIA_URL when DEBUG is False (and without a third party lib), you can just do something like this:

```
  from django.views.static import serve as mediaserve
  urlpatterns.append(url(f'^{settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip("/")}(?P<path>.*)$',
                     mediaserve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```