# nginx django project nginx.conf

Tags: python, django, nginx, centos7

I have a django project. I'm trying to get my project on the server. I have my project on the server, but I'm having a problem with nginx. In connection with this, my css is not visible.
Error:
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "etc/nginx/nginx.conf" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:7
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
enter code here
```

```
etc/nginx/nginx.conf

-# For more information on configuration, see:
-#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
-#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

-# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    -# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    -# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    -# for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       81;
        listen       [::]:81;
        server_name  __;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
        location /static/ {
        root /home/username/public_html/;
        expires 1d;
        }
    }

-# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
-#
-#    server {
-#        listen       443 ssl http2;
-#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
-#        server_name  _;
-#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
-#
-#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
-#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
-#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
-#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
-#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
-#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
-#
-#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
-#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
-#
-#        error_page 404 /404.html;
-#            location = /40x.html {
-#        }
-#
-#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
-#            location = /50x.html {
-#        }
-#    }

}
```

sudo journalctl -u nginx -n 30

Oct 15 16:20:32 test.diyetzone.com systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Oct 15 16:20:32 test.diyetzone.com nginx[1569]: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:7
Oct 15 16:20:32 test.diyetzone.com nginx[1569]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Oct 15 16:20:32 test.diyetzone.com systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 15 16:20:32 test.diyetzone.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Oct 15 16:20:32 test.diyetzone.com systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Oct 15 16:20:32 test.diyetzone.com systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.

#Stop and again

Oct 15 16:38:27 test.diyetzone.com systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Oct 15 16:38:27 test.diyetzone.com nginx[3033]: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:7
Oct 15 16:38:27 test.diyetzone.com nginx[3033]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Oct 15 16:38:27 test.diyetzone.com systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 15 16:38:27 test.diyetzone.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Oct 15 16:38:27 test.diyetzone.com systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Oct 15 16:38:27 test.diyetzone.com systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.

Comment: Check your **nginx.conf line 7** maybe you've some typo or incorrect path eg. from error `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` it should be `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: line 7 = user nginx; @AnkitTiwari

Comment: Try this command ***`sudo journalctl -u nginx -n 30`*** & add output inside your question by making [edit].

Comment: 385 lines available. I write last lines. @AnkitTiwari

Comment: Try to stop your nginx service and restart it and then check status.

Comment: thanks code is solved. but css on site not working. www.diyetzone.com @AnkitTiwari

Comment: Did you set static & media root inside your settings.py file ? If yes then run collecstatic command

Comment: And after you ran collectstatic [setup url for media & static in nginx configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392025/14457833)

Comment: settings.py true ? @AnkitTiwari
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/diyetzon/public_html/staticcollect'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'uploads')
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'